# How to draw bounding boxes after processing image with OCR using react-native-firebase-mlkit vision

Tags: react-native, ocr, react-native-firebase, firebase-mlkit

I have successfully detected text elements on an image taken with react-native-camera. The `vision().textRecognizerProcessImage(photoUri)` is successfully returning the detected text.

```
// take the photo from the camera
  takePicture = async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
        quality: 0.8,
        base64: true,
        skipProcessing: true,
      };
      const picture = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log('picture', picture);
      const {uri, width, height} = picture;
      // saving the pixel size of the selected image too 
      // for boxes position/size calculation
      this.setState({
        photoUri: uri,
        imgPixelHeight: height,
        imgPixelWidth: width,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.warn(e);
    }
  };

// processing the image to detect text
  processImage = async () => {
    const {photoUri} = this.state;
    console.log('processing Image...');
    vision()
      .textRecognizerProcessImage(photoUri)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('processImage response', result);
        this.displayProcessResult(result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('process error', error);
      });
  };

// setting the elements
  displayProcessResult(result) {
    const textElements = this.getElements(result);
    this.setState({displayRectangles: true, textElements}, () => {
      console.log('my new state', this.state);
    });
  }

// getting only the elements objects from mlkit vision
  getElements(result) {
    let allElements = [];
    const {blocks} = result;
    blocks.forEach(block => {
      const {lines} = block;
      lines.forEach(line => {
        const {elements} = line;
        allElements = [...allElements, ...elements];
      });
    });

    console.log('displayProcessResult response', allElements);

    return allElements;
  }

// drawing the boxes aronund the detected text elements
  drawRectangles() {
    const {textElements} = this.state;
    return textElements.map((element, index) => this.drawBox(element, index));
  }

  drawBox = (e, i) => {
    let [left, top, right, bottom] = e.boundingBox;
    const {imageWidh, imageHeight, imgPixelWidth, imgPixelHeight} = this.state;

    // calculating the absolute position of each box base on the pixel size of the 
    // of the image and the on screen sizes (imageWidh, imageHeight) given by react native 
    // (check the renderCameraOrImage funtion) 

    left = (left / imgPixelWidth) * imageWidh;
    right = (right / imgPixelWidth) * imageWidh;
    top = (top / imgPixelHeight) * imageHeight;
    bottom = (bottom / imgPixelHeight) * imageHeight;

    const boxWidth = Math.abs(left - right);
    const boxHeight = Math.abs(top - bottom);

    console.log('box', boxWidth, boxHeight);

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={i}
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          left,
          top,
          width: boxWidth,
          height: boxHeight,
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderColor: Colors.green,
          zIndex: 2000,
        }}
      />
    );
  };

// rendering the image or the camera base on the photoUri definition in the state
  renderCameraOrImage() {
    // render cam or img
    const {photoUri} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        {!photoUri ? (
          <RNCamera
            ref={ref => {
              this.camera = ref;
            }}
            style={styles.camera}
            type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
            flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.off}
            androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
              title: 'Permission to use camera',
              message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
              buttonPositive: 'Ok',
              buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
            }}
            zoom={this.state.zoomValue}
          />
        ) : (
          <Image
            source={{uri: this.state.photoUri}}
            style={styles.camera}
            onLayout={event => {
              var {x, y, width, height} = event.nativeEvent.layout;
              this.setState({imageWidh: width, imageHeight: height});
            }}
          />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

The result I am getting is not satisfying as the drawn boxes are off:

[image: box drawing on image result]

I need help for defining a better approach so that boxes are correctly positioned on the text elements

Comment: I tried removing resize mode from the image and modified my approach using the PixelRatio package from react native. Things seems slightly better but still not ok. Here is the complete code for the screen https://gist.github.com/ceessay/2c7f9eb4a2fb15ca5539e0f0d33d2bab